# Real Favicon Generator errors with code and will it slow site down?

Tags: html, favicon

I've used the Real Favicon Generator to generate favicons and code. I've just run my HTML and CSS through a code validator (Total Validator Pro) and it is saying that there are two errors with some of the Real Favicon Generator code:

```
E620 The 'color' attribute is not valid for this tag in this context:
         <link rel="mask-icon" href="/favicons/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#00736d">


W619 Unrecognised value for the 'name' attribute:
         <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
```

I'm a newbie so don't really know if I should be worried about this?

2.
The Real Favicon Generator creates an .xml and .json file. My website is very simple static HTML and CSS website, with no javascript, Jquery or PHP etc. It is very fast to load. Will these additional .xml and .json files slow down the load time?

Thank you

Comment: I would remove both as they won't be doing anything useful - this is a classic problem with generators

Comment: The generated code is useful. The first gives a color to Safari pinned tab icons. The second line gives a color to (I beleive) Windows tiles. I'm just concerned that the errors might negatively effect my Google ranking. And that the additional .xml and .json files might slow down the load time and again affect Google rankings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL; DR**

These two issues are harmless and the extra files won't slow down your site. You can use the package generated by RealFaviconGenerator as it is.

**In details**

RealFaviconGenerator author speaking.

The `color` is a proprietary attribute introduced by Apple. The purpose of this `link` markup is to have an icon in the pinned tabs of macOS Safari, and the `color`attribute is mandatory: if you remove if, Safari won't pick a default color but will just ignore your pinned tab icon.

The `theme-color` is for Android Chrome, in order to [style the address bar or task bar](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2014/11/Support-for-theme-color-in-Chrome-39-for-Android).

These two attributes are harmless and won't break anything. This code was [tested on several browsers](https://realfavicongenerator.net/favicon_compatibility).

In addition, [W3C validator](https://validator.w3.org/) apparently [does not report these errors anymore](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Ftest01-v0-16-attempt-1.test.realfavicongenerator.net). Could you check with your own site?

`browserconfig.xml` is for Edge and most recent versions of IE, while `manifest.json` is the [Web App Manifest](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/), mainly for Android Chrome. Browsers not interested in these files won't load them.

Comment: Thank you. I've just checked with W3C validator and you are correct it is not reporting any errors (although my Total Validator Pro app is highlighting the above things). Once again thank you for reassuring me.

Comment: Great! The change in the W3C validator is quite new, so I'm not surprised some other services still reports an issue.